Как избежать ошибок CORS через прокси в VITE React?
мне нужно обраться к удаленному API с POST запросом. При обычном запросе без прокси настроек возникает CORS ошибки. С моим запросом ошибок с CORS нет. То есть все таки я их избежал. Но не каждый день работаю с прокси и тд, поэтому хочу удостовериться может я что то все таки не правильно прописал, так как при запросе таким образом к API получаю ошибку 400 с сообщением пользователь не найден. Сразу скажу что baseURL и все остальное пишу правильно. Поэтому думаю может ли быть такое, что ошибку с CORS я обошел, раз она не попадается, но все таки что то не так написал и из за этого у меня 400.
Все ссылки тут укажу не настоящие, только для примера:
Base URL: http://mybaseurl/for/api.com/example
login: user_12
password: 123qwer
URL: v3/auth/login
Далее я делаю POST запрос, в качестве body login:string, password: string. Запрос необходим для получения токена доступа. React-проект развернут с помощью Vite.
файл vite.config.js:
           import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'


           export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://mybaseurl/for/api.com/example',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
})

*файл APP.jsx:*




import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const dataUser = {
  login: "user_12",
  passord: "123qwer",
}


function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/v3/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(dataUser),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className='gfg'>GeeksforGeeks</h1>
      <h1>Data from API:</h1>
      <pre>{data ? JSON.stringify(data) : 'Loading.'}</pre>
       
    </>
  )
}

export default App```





